# Erro ao instalar pyaudio e pocketsphinx

Tags: python, pip

Quando eu digito `sudo pip install pyaudio`  aparece essa mensagem de erro, já pesquisei no google mas não encontro uma solução:

> Command "/usr/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-eeidouwx/pyaudio/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record /tmp/pip-et7av7k2-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-eeidouwx/pyaudio/

Comment: Qual é a versão do **python** atualmente rodando na sua máquina?

Comment: Tenho instalado a 3.5 e 3.6 ... Acha que pode estar tendo algum conflito entre as duas ?

Comment: Entre essas duas acredito que não, mas foi só pre ter certeza de que não tem nenhum conflito com uma versão do **Python 2**. Tenta instalar direto do _package manager_ e vê se resolve. Ex: `sudo apt-get install python3-pyaudio`

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado funcionou agora preciso atualizar a versão do pyaudio mas agora pesquiso no google rs, Muito obrigado mesmo :D

Comment: Uma duvida Mr_Ghost por que com o pocketsphinx esse mesmo processo não funcionou ? ... estou meio perdido

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

Como mencionei nos comentários uma das soluções seria baixar direto pelo **package manager**, como no seu caso é o **Python 3** você pode usar o comando:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pyaudio
```

Porém esqueci de mencionar que dessa forma pode não trazer a versão mais atualizada. E como você perguntou logo depois sobre o *pocketsphinx*, vai ser preciso verificar o nome correto para o **package manager** dele. Esse erro com a instalação do **pip** pode está acontecendo porque ainda faltam algumas instalações de ferramentas a serem feitas, tenta rodar os comandos a baixo:

**Python 2**

Primeiro rodar esse comando `sudo apt-get install python python-all-dev python-pip build-essential swig git libpulse-dev`

E depois `pip install pocketsphinx`

**Python 3**

Primeiro rodar esse comando `sudo apt-get install python3 python3-all-dev python3-pip build-essential swig git libpulse-dev`

E depois `pip3 install pocketsphinx`

Espero ter ajudado nos dois casos =)

REFERÊNCIAS: [pyaudio](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/) e [pocketsphinx](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/reference/pocketsphinx.rst)

Comment: Cara, agora parece ter dado tudo certo, eu instalei o pyaudio direto pelo package manager mas não conseguia atualizar ele . 
Então pesquisei no site do pyaudio e no terminal digitei o comando : python -m pip install pyaudio e consegui atualizar , fiz o mesmo com o pocketsphinx e também funcionou ... Bom, Muito obrigado novamente :D

Answer (score -2):

Certo, assim mesmo como o amigão aí disse...

**Python 3**

Primeiro rodar esse comando

```
sudo apt-get install python3 python3-all-dev python3-pip build-essential swig git libpulse-dev
```

E depois `pip3 install pocketsphinx`